# Create an Issue with Jira API REST

Tags: node.js, sails.js, jira, jira-rest-api

When I try to create an Issue via the Jira API REST, I get a `500 Internal server error`, I succeeded to get an issue from a project with a get-request but when I try the post-request to create a new issue it doesn't work I get the error.

Here is my JavaScript code :

```
createIssue: function(req, res) {
  var Http = require('machinepack-http');
  process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
  Http.sendHttpRequest({
    url: '/rest/api/2/issue/',
    baseUrl: 'https://jira.mydomain.com',
    method: 'post',
    data: {
      "fields": {
        "project": {
          "key": "TEST"
        },
        "summary": "REST ye merry gentlemen.",
        "description": "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API",
        "issuetype": {
          "name": "Bug"
        }
      }
    },
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Basic YWxbG9wMS4zp0bWFuzeThYS5l1TIqaXoxOTg5554Jh"
    },
  }).exec({
    serverError: function(result) {
      res.send("server error" + JSON.stringify(result))
    },
    success: function(result) {
      res.send("issue has been created succefly");
    },
  });
}
```

Error content :

```
{
    "body": "{\"errorMessages\":[\"Internal server error\"],\"errors\":{}}",
    "headers": "{\"server\":\"nginx/1.6.0\",\"date\":\"Tue, 14 Apr 2015 13:45:38 GMT\",\"content-type\":\"application/json;charset=UTF-8\",\"transfer-encoding\":\"chunked\",\"connection\":\"close\",\"x-arequestid\":\"945x246734x1\",\"set-cookie\":[\"JSESSIONID=838923A79DA31F77BDD62510399065CF; Path=/; HttpOnly\",\"atlassian.xsrf.token=BQIV-TVLW-FGBG-OTYU|63c1b4a7b87a9367fff6185f0101c415f757e85b|lin; Path=/\"],\"x-seraph-loginreason\":\"OK\",\"x-asessionid\":\"ughpoh\",\"x-ausername\":\"alaa\",\"cache-control\":\"no-cache, no-store, no-transform\",\"x-content-type-options\":\"nosniff\"}",
    "status": 500
}
```

Comment: You get a 500 error from the Jira api or from your sails service? And was is the actual error content?

Comment: The error is from the Jira APi, I Addded the content of the error in the end of the question

Comment: Well, you found a weaknes, now you can hack it ;-) seriously though, check your server logs to see what the error is or turn error reporting to weboutput on. Error 500 is pretty non descript. It's saying we had a critical erro but we're not telling what. The message will be hidden in your server logs what is actually wrong.

Comment: Where can I find server logs please ?

Comment: I tried the same thing with a cURL-request, I've got the same 500 server error, I have the admin previleges I can create an issue directly via the Jira App but impossible via its REST API, I do not have access to the server logs.

Comment: @Alaa-GI - if you're hosting jira on your own you'll find the logs in your `$JIRA_HOME/log`-directory. If you're using the hosted jira, you might need to open a support-ticket: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/112862/how-do-i-access-the-atlassian-jira.log-file-in-an-ondemand-system

Comment: Thank you, Here is the error in the Jira log file: `Java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3962.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.common.interceptor.impl.DispatchProviderHelper$ResponseOutInvoker$1.invoke(DispatchProviderHelper.java:234`... well it's a very long error

Comment: No one can give a solution ?

Answer (score 5):

### Use `params` instead of `data`

**JS:-**

```
createIssue: function(req, res) {
  var Http = require('machinepack-http');
  process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
  Http.sendHttpRequest({
    url: '/rest/api/2/issue/',
    baseUrl: 'https://jira.mydomain.com',
    method: 'post',
    params: {
      "fields": {
        "project": {
          "key": "TASC"
        },
        "summary": "REST ye merry gentlemen.",
        "description": "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API",
        "issuetype": {
          "name": "Bug"
        }
      }
    },
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "Basic YWxbG9wMS4zp0bWFuzeThYS5l1TIqaXoxOTg5554Jh"
    },
  }).exec({
    serverError: function(result) {
      res.send("server error" + JSON.stringify(result))
    },
    success: function(result) {
      res.send("issue has been created succefly");
    },
  });
}
```

<kbd>[Reference](http://node-machine.org/machinepack-http/send-http-request)</kbd>

Comment: It dosen't work, here is the server response : `error: Sending 500 ("Server Error") response:  ReferenceError: data is not defined`

Comment: Then your code is using `data` somewhere where it shouldn't. The docs clearly use `params` and not `data`: http://node-machine.org/machinepack-http/send-http-request.

Comment: I put the node.js aside, and test a post-request with a cURL, to be sure it's not a syntax error, the same story i got an internal server error 500, here is what the log file says : `Java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor3962.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.common.interceptor.impl.DispatchProviderHelper$ResponseOutInvoker$1.invoke(DispatchProviderHelper.java:234` ...

Comment: ... `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.atlassian.jira.rest.v2.issue.IssueInputParametersAssembler$IssueInputParametersBuilder.initProjectAndIssueType(IssueInputParametersAssembler.java:293)
 at com.atlassian.jira.rest.v2.issue.IssueInputParametersAssembler$IssueInputParametersBuilder.buildForCreate(IssueInputParametersAssembler.java:258)
 at com.atlassian.jira.rest.v2.issue.IssueInputParametersAssembler.makeCreateAssembler(IssueInputParametersAssembler.java:122)
 ..... `

Comment: Any other solution please ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's expecting some non-null value when it's trying to parse the `project` or `issuetype` fields, though without the full stacktrace, it's hard to be sure.

You might try adding an `id` property to both the `project` and `issuetype` fields:

```
params: {
  "fields": {
    "project": {
      "key": "TASC",
      "id": "10001"
    },
    "summary": "REST ye merry gentlemen.",
    "description": "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API",
    "issuetype": {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Bug"
    }
  }
}
```

Obviously you'll want to make sure to use an appropriate value in both cases.